# how to export last five minutes records in postgres usng pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

how to export last 5 minutes records from table in Postgres any one let me know

i have query below

```
SELECT * 
FROM emp 
WHERE "created_at" >= NOW() - INTERVAL '5 minutes';
```

i want to export using pg_dump

am using below syntax

```
pg_dump -U localhost -p 5432 --username "postgres"   --dbname "dbname" -t public.emp --verbose -f "path/table.backup"
```

By using this i exporting all data of table

but i need some data using query

please hel any one

Answer (score 3):

pg_dump will dump whole tables only.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html

To export part of a table use copy.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-copy.html